# Why are my pointer assignments causing program to crash

Tags: c, pointers

I have written the code below as a small program to test out before writing a larger program based on the same basic principle. I had it working yesterday, but it's getting hung up this morning, and I can't figure out why.

The code is getting hung up at:    new_rec->next = head;

Please have a look at the code below, and thanks for your help.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fptr;


struct list {
  char string[256];
  char *ptr;
  struct list *next;
};

unsigned int breakRemove(char string1[]);

int main(void)
{
  if ((fptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\mgreene\\Documents\\EmailTemplates\\TestList.txt", "w")) == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.");
    exit(1);
  }


  int i, j, k, count=0;
  char ans[256];
  char *pAns;
  pAns = ans;
  struct list *ptr = NULL;

  do
  {
    puts("\nEnter some text: ");
    fgets(ans, 256, stdin);
    breakRemove(ans);
    if (pAns != '\0');
    {
      count++;
      printf("\n%d.  You typed:\"%s\"", count, pAns); //test for correct pAns pointer assignment
    }

    struct list list1;
    struct list *head = NULL;
    struct list *new_rec = NULL;
    struct list *curr_rec = NULL;
    struct list *next_rec = NULL;


    new_rec = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));

    if (!new_rec)
    {
      puts("\nMemory Allocation Error");
      exit(1);
    }
    puts("\nFirst Memory Allocation Successful."); //acknowledge successful memory allocation
    ptr = pAns;
    printf("\nptr = %s", ptr); //test for pointer assignment
    printf("\npAns = %s", pAns); //test for pointer assignment
    head = ptr;
    printf("\nhead = %s", head);// test for pointer assignment

    printf("\nProblem is new_rec->next=head."); //test to isolate problem.

    new_rec->next = head;
    printf("\nnew_rec->next = ", new_rec->next);
    head = new_rec;
    curr_rec = head;
    while (curr_rec->next != NULL)
    {
      curr_rec = curr_rec->next;
    }


    puts("\nList Pointer Memory Allocation Successful.");
    curr_rec->next = new_rec;


    new_rec->next = NULL;
    strcpy(new_rec->string, ans);
    printf("\n%s", curr_rec->string);

    if (list1.string != '\0')
    {
      fprintf(fptr, "\n%d. %s", count, curr_rec->string);
    }

  }while (*pAns != '\0');

}

unsigned int breakRemove(char string1[]) //Function for removing line breaks from fgets.
{
  unsigned int lenString;

  lenString = strlen(string1);

  if (string1[lenString-1]=='\n')
  {
    string1[lenString-1]='\0';
  }
  return (unsigned char)string1;
}
```

Comment: Hung up!? It stops executing at that specific line? Like you've set a breakpoint?

Comment: Please narrow down your problem using a debugger, and only post a _minimal_ reproducing example. I'd start by fixing all the warnings you should be getting. And if you're not getting any, turn on your warning levels (to the max).

Comment: I get two warnings. One for     ptr = pAns, and another in my breakremove function. Those are the only warnings I get. It doesn't stop like I've inserted a break, it just hangs on the previously mentioned line.

Comment: `if (pAns != '\0');` : the semicolon at the end is certainly not intended.

Answer (score 3):

Enable the warnings in your compiler. I got:

```
../main.c:53:9: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
../main.c:54:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct list *’ [-Wformat]
../main.c:57:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct list *’ [-Wformat]
../main.c:62:5: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
../main.c:44:18: warning: unused variable ‘next_rec’ [-Wunused-variable]
../main.c:23:13: warning: unused variable ‘k’ [-Wunused-variable]
../main.c:23:10: warning: unused variable ‘j’ [-Wunused-variable]
../main.c:23:7: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
../main.c: In function ‘breakRemove’:
../main.c:93:10: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
```

Fix them for a good start. :)

For example, the first warning is coming from

```
ptr = pAns;
```

and then this will be `head`. That's why your program crashes (one of the reasons probably).

You have

```
char *pAns;
struct list *ptr = NULL;
```

and then you assign the one to the other. This doesn't make sense. You should try/study harder, since the errors are many for an answer to fix them.

Another example is here:

```
if (pAns != '\0')
  ;                <-- suspicious semicolon, remove it
{
  count++;
  printf("\n%d.  You typed:\"%s\"", count, pAns);  //test for correct pAns pointer assignment
}
```

---

To turn the warnings on in code blocks, you could do this:

"check the option "Enable all compiler warnings" in the settings=>configure plugins=>compiler"

or do this:

[image]

that I found [here](http://bytefreaks.net/howtos/enable-all-warnings-on-codeblocks).

Comment: I only got two errors. the    ptr = pAns, and one in breakRemove. I'm using Code::Blocks to compile the program. In terms of studying harder, this only my third month of coding. :)

Comment: Well @Matt that's OK, we are all were beginners (maybe I am still one) at sometime. I updated my answer.

Comment: @G.Samaras: The only thing that bothers me with this answer is that you put 50 times more effort into it than the OP did in his question.

Comment: Will agree @ereOn but I managed to stop myself from debugging entirely the code. I hope that Matt will grasp the content of my answer and start debugging his code.

Comment: @G.Samaras: Thanks for your assistance with the debugger in Code::Blocks and the code in general. I appreciate it.

Comment: @ereOn: I'm not sure what you mean with respect to effort, but considering that I'm trying to learn C on my own while working 50+ hours a week and having a family, I'd say I'm putting a good deal of effort into it. I had a question and I asked. I apologize if my question was too basic or simple, or otherwise violates some etiquette I'm not aware of, but I'm not sure how to learn other than ask.

Comment: @Matt: Are you implying that the time of people that answer your question is less important than your own ? We all work 50+ hours/week and have families and priorities: it would have taken you 10 minutes to write a better, well formatted, and minimal question (and perhaps would have helped you finding your own errors in the process). Instead, you just dumped a wall of code and asked for people to fix it for you. There is nothing wrong in asking, but surely there is something wrong in doing so lazily. Isolating and reproducing problems is a part of learning: you must realize that.

Comment: @ereOn: I was implying nothing other than what I stated: I had a question so I asked. Obviously, I'm unfamiliar with the etiquette, but based my question on my 2 or so months of lurking here. In some cases, people ask to see more code, so I erred on the side of providing a complete picture. With respect to finding my own errors, I sat and changed the code several different ways, tried different pointer methods, consulted the couple of text books I have, looked on line, and then after exhausting what seems to be the options I have on my own, I asked a question.

Comment: @ereOn: Furthermore, I asked no one to fix my code, I pointed out where the code seemed to no be working and asked if anyone understood why it might hang up at that spot, which is actually a pretty specific question. In addition, at this point, I wouldn't even know which code to isolate. Do include the whole loop? Do I need the struct defs? I have no idea what minimal code I should have even posted. Finally, I do realize that isolating and reproducing problems is part of learning, which is why I isolated my code to that specific portion. I pulled parts of it from a book that works fine.

Comment: @Matt: From your [last 3 questions](http://goo.gl/8VAoQg), none got a positive score. And from a quick glance at them, I would assume that's for the same reason: lack of *apparent* effort. Ignore this if you will, but it clearly says something about how you ask your questions. Keep in mind I'm not being harsh or mean here: improving the way you ask your questions **will** actually get people to produce better answers, helping **you** in return. Perhaps you really spent hours on writing and debugging but in the end it doesn't matter if it doesn't show in the questions.

Comment: @ereOn: Thanks for the words of wisdom. I noticed that about my questions too, I just don't know how to better ask a question. As I stated above, I'm only asking what I don't seem to understand at the time; I'm not really sure how else to do this. If you don't mind, let me ask you about this specific case: How should I have asked this question differently to generate a more positive response? Thanks.

Comment: @Matt: start by reading and fixing issues mentionned in the comments. See comments as people that would love to help you but can't because something is unclear or missing. Also make sure you employ the right terms: "The code is getting hung up" is not an usual term. Do not only answer to comments: update the question to fix it. You owe it to the people willing to help you as much as to those who might look at your question in the future in quest for the same answer. Finally, your code is way too big. Comment out some portions and try until the bug disappears or use a debugger. Good luck!